# How to fix Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type in getMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two spring boot entities in a relation. MeetingSettings and MeetingTimes. MeetingSettings can have a infinite number of MeetingTimes. Saving them works without any problem. MeetingTimes has the meetingName property as a foreign key from MeetingSettings. What I now am trying to do is to get all MeetingTimes by name, but I am getting the following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.dates.MeetingTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Testtewhuete'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Testtewhuete"]
```

As I understood the error it is trying to convert the String meetingName I am giving to a Long value, but I am not mapping them with the meetingName and meetingName is in MeetingSettings and the database a string. So why does this error occur? I could not find any solution for this. Can someone have a look at my code?

MeetingSettings Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Setter
@Getter
public class MeetingsSetting implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingTimes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" , referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

MeetingTimeService where I am doing the get:

```
@Service
public class MeetingTimeService {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeRepository meetingTimeRepository;

                            public List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByName(MeetingTime meetingName){
                return meetingTimeRepository.findMeetingTimeByMeetingName(meetingName);
            }
}
```

MeetingTimeRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingTimeRepository extends JpaRepository<MeetingTime, Long> {

    List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByMeetingName(MeetingTime meetingName);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could change it by changing the jpa repo method to:

```
List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByMeetingName_MeetingName(String meetingName);
```

But can someone explain me why this worked now?

What does

```
findMeetingTimeByMeetingName_MeetingName
```

this part change? This is what jparepo had recommended me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of `findMeetingTimeByMeetingName(MeetingTime meetingName)`

try this code

```
 @Query("SELECT mt FROM MeetingTime mt WHERE mt.meetingName.meetingName=?1")
        List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeBymeetingName(String meetingName);
```

or

```
@Query("SELECT mt FROM MeetingTime mt WHERE mt.meetingName=?1")
    List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByMeetingsSetting(MeetingsSetting meetingName);
```